# Span$\left( \left\{ v_{1},\ldots ,v_{n}\right\} \right)$ is subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $f$. Note that Span$\left( \left\{ v_{1},\ldots ,v_{n}\right\} \right)$ is subspace of $V$. But,Keith Condrad says that it may not be the whole space, of course. **Can you give an example this?**

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/dimension.pdf Page.1

Comment: Take $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathrm{span}(\{v_1\})$. This is obviously gives not the whole space $\mathbb R^2$ but just a linne through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V = \Bbb{R}^3$, and consider $W = \mathrm{span}(\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\})$. Then $W$ is the $xy$-plane, which is not all of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

It's only the whole space if $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is (or contains) a basis for the space.

Example:

Consider the two sets $\{(1,0)\}$ and $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$.  Both of these are subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ (i.e. the plane).  The span of the first set is just the $x$-axis (and thus a line), but the span of the second one is *all* of $\Bbb R^2$ (the entire plane).